# Using multi-curl for faster responses

Tags: php, curl

I am using cURL instead of `file_get_contents()`, but I am interested in utilizing cURL multi function.

At present I am using below code which is doing one by one and I have read that cURL multi can reduce the time and improve the performance.

Here is my code. How can I make this using cURL multi?

```
$res2 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM `xxxx` where status = '1' LIMIT 3");

while($result = $res2->fetch_assoc()){

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $websitelink);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);

  $doc = new DOMDocument();
  libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
  $doc->loadHTML($result);


  $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    $data = get_headers($tag->getAttribute('src'),1);
    $op7=''.$tag->getAttribute('src').'';
    echo $op7;
  }

}
```

Comment: We're not here to write your code for you. Read the documentation, it has examples. Once you have it written, if you can't get it to work post what you tried and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php